# SSAS: Errors in the OLAP storage engine: The attribute key cannot be found when processing

Tags: ssas, olap, olap-cube

In my searching, I have seen this error text been asked in different contexts, but specifically, I want to know if I am missing something here.

In a basic setup, I have 1 measure table and 1 dimension table in my DSV. In my test, the measure table has about half of the sold products, but the dimension table has info on the entire product catalog.

The relationship has the measure table as the foreign key and the dimension as the primary. Case is not an issue as both are integers.

What am I doing wrong? I have tried reversing the relationship and I always process the dimension in full before processing the cube in full whenever I make a change.

To avoid the errors, I can set the ignore key errors thing or ensure that the dimension only contains the products that the measure contains. I can do the latter, but I feel that using an unfiltered reference table is cleaner and more efficient - it's on that note that I say "am I missing something?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apologies for wasting everyone's time on this one. I was going to delete the question but thought I would share my self-rectified findings:

In my above example, I failed to mention that the dimension table also had links to other tables. Missing (null) references between those tables caused the dimension member to be missing when processed hence the 'attribute key could not be found' when the cube was processed!